# How to run two Jquery animates with chaining simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to make an object move back and forth while the object changes it opacity at the same time.

I tried with queue and callback function to make this work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
   $("#divv").animate({left:'+=500'},"slow","linear")
     .animate({left:'-=500'},"slow","linear")
     .animate({left:'-=500'},"slow","linear")
    .animate({left:'+=500'},"slow","linear")

$("#divv").animate({opacity:'-=0.8'},"slow","linear")
   .animate({opacity:'+=0.8'},"slow","linear")
   .animate({opacity:'-=0.8'},"slow","linear")
   .animate({opacity:'+=0.8'},"slow","linear")
```

})
 });

The object moves left and right, then it changes the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate multiple properties at once, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $("#divv").animate({left:'+500', opacity:'-=0.8'}, "slow", "linear");
    });
});
```

Hope this works!